# Convert JavaScript string object in to array element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-objects

I have a variable which value is coming like this:

```
"
  traffic





  engagement





  conversion




"
```

I want to convert it to: ["traffic", "engagement", "conversion"] .
Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Where is the data for that variable coming from because, as it stands, that variable would give you a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

If we ignore the errors in string (as @Andy said), and we just have a string with words separated by an unknown amount of space, such as this:

```
var str = "      traffic      engagement     conversion";
```

This regexp should to the trick:

```
var arr = str.match(/[^\s]+/g);
```

It means get all sequences that don't include spaces of any kind.

Comment: or simply `/\S+/g`...

Comment: @rails-master - a Confirm Answer would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option for you:

```
            </html>


            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <body>

            <p>Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>

            <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

            <p id="demo"></p>

            <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var str = "How are you doing today?";
                var res = str.split(" ");
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
            }
            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how:

var array = string.split(',');

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), mostly helpful for the possibly unexpected behavior of the limit parameter. (Hint: "a,b,c".split(",", 2) comes out to ["a", "b"], not ["a", "b,c"].)